# Why is a function without argument identifiers valid in C++?

Tags: c++, function, syntax

Given a function in C++ with arguments that are only types and have no identifiers,

```
 void foo1(int, int, int){cout << "called foo1";}
```

I can call it as such:

```
int main()
{
    foo1(10, 10, 10);
}
```

Why is this a valid construct in C++? Is this just an idiosyncrasy of C++, or does this kind of declaration actually have some purpose? Can we actually access the arguments that have been passed in somehow?
(This kind of method declaration will not work in Java.)

Comment: Silencing warnings about unused parameters.

Comment: I got no warnings in Visual Studio using default settings for the above code.

Comment: Sometimes you just need some specific signature to comply with some interface. But don't really need the parameter.

Comment: @programmerravi That's precisely what was stated in the comments. You don't get unused parameter warnings if you don't give a name to parameter, opposed to giving it a name, and not using it.

Comment: Some times you need an argument you will never use. The most common case may be to disambiguate between overloads. A standard example would be `operator++(int)` vs `operator++()` (member pre and post increment operators). It can also be used with tag dispatch systems.

Comment: "will not work in Java" - Part of the reason is that in Java there is no distinction between declaration and definition.  Another part is that they're more "protective" of the programmer and have deemed a lot of things as unnecessary and possibly confusing to the programmer, this could be one such.

Comment: It's not idissyncrasy of C/C++: the construct is invalid in C.

Answer (score 46):

Consider a case where you are required to provide a function that meets the following prototype

```
void dostuff(int x, int y, int z);
```

And say you are operating in a 2D space and do not use `z` inside your implementation. You can

```
void dostuff(int x, int y, int z)
{
    // use x and y
}
```

and just ignore `z`, but the compiler will likely spot that you have defined but not used `z` and warn you that you could be making a mistake. Instead you can

```
void dostuff(int x, int y, int )
{
    // use x and y
}
```

and leave out the definition of `z`. The compiler will accept and silently discard the third parameter because it knows you don't want it.

You do not want to simply turn off the warning because of errors like this

```
void dostuff(int x, int y, int z)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < MAX; z++)
    {
        // use x and y and z, the local z. 
    }
}
```

Where a poorly-named loop index shadows the parameter `z`. The caller's input is now ignored and this could have bad consequences. This error is often hard to spot with the mark 1 eyeball, especially if the local `z` is buried somewhere deep in a complex function.

Anytime the compiler can pick off a possible bug in your code, take advantage. It means less work for you.

Comment: I personally like to materialize the unused argument with comments: `int /*z*/`. This serves as a reminder of what is the argument and what it could be used for.

Comment: For your example of shadowing, I think the compiler should (also) warn about the shadowing itself; I can't think of too many situations where we'd intentionally shadow a parameter or local variable with another local variable, even if the shadowee is still used somewhere outside the shadower's scope.

Answer (score 17):

A declaration like

```
void foo1(int, int, int){cout << "called foo1";}
```

clearly shows in the declaration, that you want to fulfill a requirement with your function - e.g. override a specific function in the base class or interface, which e.g. could be declared there as

```
virtual void foo1(int something, int another, int andAnother) = 0;
```

BUT you don't intend to use the parameters which are handed over to you.

Another example would be if you want to hand over the function to e.g. another function which expects a function pointer to a void function with three int parameters.

```
void giveMeFoo( void (*fn)(int, int, int) ) { ... }
```

Additionally, higher warning levels issue a warning, if parameters are declared, which are not evaluated in the function body. You can avoid that by leaving the parameter names away.

The parameters without names are then indeed not accessible in the function body anymore - on purpose. user4581301 has nicely described, why.

Declaring a standalone function without parameter names as in your example is allowed because of the usages described above, but it obviously makes no sense in most cases. An example where it does make sense is in the comment section. Another example of a standalone function without parameter names could be, if your'e writing a library and want to either maintain backward compatibility (your library function does not need the parameter anymore, but you don't want to break the public header declaration) or you want to reserve a parameter for future use.

Comment: Free functions with unnamed arguments is not nonsense, it's just uncommon. See [a standard example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec).

Comment: OK thx... a dummy parameter is a non-nonsense usage... but pretty rare :D

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**. It is legal in C++.

**C++11 n3337 standard 8.4.1(p6) Function definitions:**

> Note: Unused parameters need not be named. For example,
>
> ```
> void print(int a, int) {
>     std::printf("a = %d\n", a);
> }
> ```

C++14 standard:

> [ 8.3.5.11] **An identifier can optionally be provided as a parameter name; if present in a function definition , it names a parameter
>   (sometimes called “formal argument”).** [Note: In particular, parameter
>   names are also optional in function definitions and names used for a
>   parameter in different declarations and the definition of a function
>   need not be the same.]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza Strictly speaking, it does. Why is it valid? Because the standard explicitly says so. It doesn't go into full detail, of course.

Comment: I don't think "Why is it valid?" "Because it is" answers the question. Edit: actually, I guess it answers "Can we actually access the arguments that have been passed in somehow?"

Comment: @JAB This doesn't tell us the why, it just states the fact.

Answer (score 7):

It's legal, and if you're wondering why:

> Typically, unnamed arguments arise from the simplification of code or
>   from planning ahead for extensions. In both cases, leaving the
>   argument in place, although unused, ensures that callers are not
>   affected by the change.

Excerpt From: Bjarne Stroustrup. “The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition.”

Answer (score 0):

**The idea is that you might want to change the function
definition to use the placeholder later, without changing all the
code where the function is called.**

Arguments in a function declaration can be declared without
identifiers. When these are used with default arguments, it can look
a bit funny. You can end up with :

```
void f(int x, int = 0, float = 1.1);
```

In C++ you don’t need identifiers in the function definition, either:

```
void f(int x, int, float flt) { /* ... */ }
```

In the function body, `x` and flt can be referenced, but not the
middle argument, because it has no name. Function calls must still
provide a value for the placeholder, though: `f(1)` or `f(1,2,3.0)`. This
syntax allows you to put the argument in as a placeholder without
using it.

Answer (score 0):

Unnamed parameters can also be used for the tag dispatch idiom:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t){ 
    foo(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_same_v<std::remove_ref<std::remove_const<T>>>, std::string>); // do something special with strings

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t, std::false_type); // note no parameter name

template<typename T>
void foo(T&& t, std::true_type);
```