# How to extract info into a struct and output to a file c++

Tags: c++

Im just learning about structs and am a bit stuck. im trying to extract info from a file containing course info(Class, time, dates etc...) However with my code so far the only thing being outputted into the newly created file is just the cout text I wrote. Any idea on how I can fix this?
Heres my code so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

//Holds all the class information
struct Course{

    string courseName;
    string courseNum;
    string courseDay;
    string courseTime;
    string courseLoc;

};

//Extracts data from the file with the course information
Course getInfo(ifstream &inFile);

//Creates a file with the data from 'getInfo'
void writeInfo(ofstream &outFile, Course course);

int main(){

    ifstream inFile; //link to input file
    ofstream outFile; //link to output file
    Course course; //holds all course info

    inFile.open("Courses.txt"); //opens textfile
    outFile.open("Courses.dat"); //creates new file

    course = getInfo(inFile); //priming read

   while (inFile) {

        writeInfo(outFile, course); //write info to output file

        course = getInfo(inFile); //get info from input file

    }

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

}

Course getInfo(ifstream &inFile){

    Course course;

    inFile >> course.courseName >> course.courseNum >> course.courseDay;
    inFile >> course.courseTime  >> course.courseLoc;

    return course;

}

void writeInfo(ofstream &outFile, Course){
    Course course;

    outFile << "Class: " << course.courseName << " Class ID: " << course.courseNum << " Meeting Days: " << course.courseDay << " Class Time: " << course.courseTime << " Class Location: " << course.courseLoc << endl;


}
```

Comment: That's not how you pass a variable to a function. Maybe review that chapter before trying to move on to other things. You are creating a new empty `Course` in your `writeInfo` function and printing that to your file. So obviously it will be empty.

Comment: It's as simple as changing `void writeInfo(ofstream &outFile, Course){
    Course course; outFile << ... }` to `void writeInfo(ofstream &outFile, Course course){ outFile << ...}` I'd count this as typo.

Answer (score 1):

Let'stake a closer look at what the code asks for

```cpp
void writeInfo(ofstream &outFile, // take an ofstream as a reference parameter. 
                                  // Call it OutFile
              Course) // take a Course as a parameter. Don't give it an identifier
                      // this makes the provided Course unusable inside the function
{ 
    Course course; // define a new, local Course named course that has been default 
                   // initialized

    outFile << "Class: " << course.courseName 
            << " Class ID: " << course.courseNum 
            << " Meeting Days: " << course.courseDay 
            << " Class Time: " << course.courseTime 
            << " Class Location: " << course.courseLoc 
            << endl; // print out the contents of the local Course
}
```

Not what we want. We want to print out the course that was passed in. Let's make that happen

```cpp
void writeInfo(ofstream &outFile, // take an ofstream as a reference parameter. 
                                  // Call it OutFile
              Course course) // take a Course as a value parameter. Call it course.
                             // This will make a new course that is a copy of the Course 
                             // used as an argument by the caller. Note that a smart  
                             // compiler willeliminate copying where it can, but it might
                             // not recognize that the copy is not required here.
{ 
    outFile << "Class: " << course.courseName 
            << " Class ID: " << course.courseNum 
            << " Meeting Days: " << course.courseDay 
            << " Class Time: " << course.courseTime 
            << " Class Location: " << course.courseLoc 
            << endl; // print out the contents of the Course parameter
}
```

Now let's make it better

```cpp
void writeInfo(ofstream &outFile, // take an ofstream as a reference parameter. 
                                  // Call it OutFile
              const Course & course) // take a Course as a constant reference parameter. 
                                     // Call it course
                                     // As a reference the argument will not be copied, 
                                     // and as a constant it cannot be accidentally changed 
                                     // and can accepta short-lived temporary value that 
                                     // you otherwise cannot use as an argument for a 
                                     // reference. This is handy sometimes. You see it
                                     // all the time with string literals being 
                                     // transformed into temporary std::strings
{ 
    outFile << "Class: " << course.courseName 
            << " Class ID: " << course.courseNum 
            << " Meeting Days: " << course.courseDay 
            << " Class Time: " << course.courseTime 
            << " Class Location: " << course.courseLoc 
            << endl; // print out the contents of the Course parameter
}
```

Why an unnamed parameter is allowed in C++ is asked and answered in [Why is a function without argument identifiers valid in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230544/why-is-a-function-without-argument-identifiers-valid-in-c/47230803#47230803)